# 2D Array Average - Convolution - C Program

Tags: arrays, c, 2d, average, convolution

[image]

I need help with my program. I need it to calculate the 3x3 average and then go and and calculate the next. This is what i got so far, it‘s only to calculate the average of all and now I‘m stuck…

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ROWS 5
#define COLS 7

int main(void){
    float in_sum = 0;
    float *in_matrix[ROWS][COLS];
    float in_avg;

    float matr[ROWS][COLS]={{1.5, 5, 6, 12, 13, 7, 80},
                            {50, 6.5, 23, 77, 17, 8.5, 28},
                            {43.5, 78, 8, 9, 34.5, 10, 95},
                            {75, 44, 40, 29, 39, 5, 99.5},
                            {18, 86, 68, 92, 10.5, 11, 4}};

    printf("Matrix Input:\n");

        for(int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++){
                printf("%.2f ", matr[i][j]);
                    if(j==6){
                        printf("\n");
                    }
            }
        }
        printf("\nMatrix Output: \n");
        int j = 0, nr = 3, nc = 3;
        for (int i = 0; i < nr; i++){
            for(j = 0; j < nc; j++){
                in_sum = in_sum + matr[i][j];
            }
        }
        in_avg = in_sum/(ROWS*COLS);
        for (int i=0; i< ROWS; i++){
            for (int j=0; j< COLS; j++){
            printf("%.2f", in_avg);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        in_matrix[ROWS][COLS] = &in_sum;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: describing photo is on the link

Comment: On an unrelated note, instead of `if (j == 6) { printf("\n"); }`, just put the printing of the newline outside the inner loop. Like `for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) { ... } printf("\n");`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is not clear exactly what your problem is. Is the code not doing what it should do? How so? What have you tried to get it to work? Where are you stuck?

Comment: The code doesn't compile as it's missing defines for ROWS, COLS and #includes.   Diagram doesn't match data or even the dimensions.

Comment: @AllanWind ```#include <stdio.h> #define ROWS 5 #define COLS 7```

Comment: You declare `float *in_matrix[ROWS][COLS];` but then access it out of bounds with `in_matrix[ROWS][COLS] = &in_sum;`

Comment: @Fra93 Yup, op should update question so everyone doesn't have to figure this out.

Comment: my bad, I forgot to put the first lines, defining ROWS and COLS

Comment: No apologies necessary just edit question to clarify.

Comment: Our `int j = 0` is shadowed by the loop variables.

Comment: In the last loop you print out in_avg for each position for the matrix.  This is not even close to being working.  Output array is the wrong size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the `Sum` value when the computation range moves to right.

```
#define ROWS (5)
#define COLS (7)

float SumOf3Elem( const float *p ){ return p[0]+p[1]+p[2];  }
float Add4th_Sub1st( float S, const float *p ){ return S + p[3] - p[0]; }

int main()
{
    float M[ROWS][COLS] = {
        {1.5, 5, 6, 12, 13, 7, 80},
        {50, 6.5, 23, 77, 17, 8.5, 28},
        {43.5, 78, 8, 9, 34.5, 10, 95},
        {75, 44, 40, 29, 39, 5, 99.5},
        {18, 86, 68, 92, 10.5, 11, 4}
    };

    for( int Top=0; Top+2<ROWS; ++Top )
    {
        float Sum = SumOf3Elem(M[Top]) + SumOf3Elem(M[Top+1]) + SumOf3Elem(M[Top+2]);
        printf( "%f ", Sum/9.0f );

        for( int Left=0; Left+3<COLS; ++Left )
        {
            for( int i=0; i<3; ++i )
            {   Sum = Add4th_Sub1st( Sum, M[Top+i]+Left );  }

            printf( "%f ", Sum/9.0f );
        }
        printf( "\n" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice.  Add the missing include?  If you retain the partial sums you should be able to do even better (the 3 values you subtract you already summed earlier and when you advance to the next rows you could do the row version of `Add4th_Sub1st()`).

Answer (score 0):

The code you shared isn't even close to being working.  Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define COLS 7
#define OVER 3
#define ROWS 5

float sum(size_t cols, float *matrix) {
    float s = 0;
    for(size_t row = 0; row < OVER; row++) {
        for(size_t col = 0; col < OVER; col++) {
            s += matrix[row * cols + col];
        }
    }
    return s / (OVER * OVER);
}

int main(void) {
    float matrix[ROWS][COLS] = {
        {1.5, 5, 6, 12, 13, 7, 80},
        {50, 6.5, 23, 77, 17, 8.5, 28},
        {43.5, 78, 8, 9, 34.5, 10, 95},
        {75, 44, 40, 29, 39, 5, 99.5},
        {18, 86, 68, 92, 10.5, 11, 4}
    };
    for(size_t row=0; row < ROWS - OVER + 1; row++) {
        for(size_t col=0; col < COLS - OVER + 1; col++) {
            printf("%.1f%c",
                sum(COLS, &matrix[row][col]),
                col + 1 < COLS - OVER + 1 ? ' ' : '\n');
        }
    }
}
```

and example run:

```
24.6 24.9 22.2 20.9 32.6
40.9 34.9 30.7 25.4 37.4
51.2 50.4 36.7 26.7 34.3
```

As the input matrix is hard-coded this works, but if you need a generic function you should check that the input is at least a OVER x OVER matrix.

The `sum()` performs 8 additions for `matrix[0][0]` and then another 8 additions for the `matrix[0][1]`.  We could clearly do better.  For example by retaining the last sum and subtract what is no longer in the window and add what now is.  Caching of partial results.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort! Is there another solution without using sizeof and size_t, we got told to not use it since we havent learnt it. So sorry about the circumstances!

Comment: I updated answer using ROWS and COLS instead of sizeof.

Comment: Please make sure you accept the best answer (click the checkmark) so we know you are all set.  @fana's has that optimization that I mentioned at the cost of a little more complexity.

Comment: Oops I missed that one. Thank you both!!